Dried out wood diving board needs refinishing
Old diving diving board in need of refinishing. Some wood filler required as well.
Is linseed oil a good choice?
What type of exterior wood filler is recommended?

How old is old?  It seems to be recommended to be replace around ten years, more or less depending on condition.  Ten years is for a well maintained board.

IDK that wood filler is appropriate for a diving board.  Might be time to simply replace.

Linseed oil is a good choice and so is a quality marine varnish. Wood filler is not such a good idea. It has a tendency to crack and crumble when used in small repairs and if you need larger repairs, then the board could be in danger of splitting. Living in South Florida and I don't see any wood diving boards around any more. A smart choice would be to replace it.
